# Automation Steps not firing for custom screen?

Tags: acumatica

I have used automation steps to add an action menu to an existing screen, add approval automation and other automations to an existing screen, and control fields/values of existing screens.  Each of those cases appear to work fine.  However, I have added a new custom screen that does not require approvals, and automation steps seem to do nothing for me other than adding an action item to the menu.

What would prevent my custom screen from executing my simple automation steps?  I have 1 view set as the data member for both the form and tab in a form/tab screen used to break up the data to keep the data simple for the end user to view.  The only thing working is that the Action menu option "Convert to Repair" is added to the screen, although it is not disabled as intended nor the status updated when the hold checkbox is changed.

Automation Definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Screens>
    <Screen ScreenID="ZI302000">
        <Step StepID="Hold -&gt; Open" Description="Hold -&gt; Open" GraphName="SSCS.IN.ZZINNcmTagEntry" ViewName="NCMTags" TimeStampName="Tstamp">
            <Filter FieldName="Hold" Condition="Equals" Value="False" Value2="False" Operator="And" />
            <Filter FieldName="Status" Condition="Equals" Value="H" Operator="And" />
            <Action ActionName="*" IsDefault="1">
                <Fill FieldName="Status" Value="O" />
            </Action>
            <Action ActionName="Action" MenuText="Convert to Repair">
                <Fill FieldName="@ActionName" Value="ConvertRepair" />
            </Action>
        </Step>
        <Step StepID="On Hold" Description="On Hold" GraphName="SSCS.IN.ZZINNcmTagEntry" ViewName="NCMTags" TimeStampName="Tstamp">
            <Filter FieldName="Hold" Condition="Equals" Value="True" Value2="False" Operator="And" />
            <Action ActionName="*" IsDefault="1">
                <Fill FieldName="Status" Value="H" />
            </Action>
            <Action ActionName="Action" MenuText="Convert to Repair" IsDisabled="1">
                <Fill FieldName="@ActionName" Value="ConvertRepair" />
            </Action>
        </Step>
    </Screen>
</Screens>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, it seems the automation steps referenced a node id of an earlier version of the page.  After experimenting with some formatting of the page, I removed it and started over.  By not removing the old automation steps entirely, the system was firing automation for a page referenced by an outdated node id.

Solution:  Delete the automation steps entirely and start over.  In my case, I deleted the automation definition as well because I had tried deleting the automation steps before but not the automation definition with no success.  I also deleted the site map to the page, the files from the customization project, the files from the OS, and recreated it all from scratch.  Once confirmed that automation steps were working on the newly recreated page, I was able to go to a backup copy of the aspx file and paste the contents into my new page aspx file in the customization project to restore all my work on the layout and settings.

Comment: On other important element that bit me when I went back through the cleanup.  Remember to push the automation steps into the automation definition and ACTIVATE IT.  While it was working at one point, I broke it again doing cleanup.  With a coworker, we walked start to finish through the process again and found that I had forgotten to add the automation definition back.  When I did, it still didn't work... until I clicked ACTIVATE.  (We thought the automation definition was just a means to export/import for migration from DEV to Production, but it seems to be more. Lesson learned.)